Are there Functions $f$ and $g$ such that $g$ is Bijective & is the Dirichlet Inverse of an Arithmetic Function $f$?
Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be a function. I was wondering if, there is a function $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $(f * g)(n)= \epsilon (n) = (g * f)(n)$ and $(f \circ g)(n) = id(n) = (g \circ f)(n)$ for all positive integers $n$, where $*$ is the Dirichlet convolution, $\circ$ represent the composition of functions, $id(n) = n$ for all positive integers $n$, and
$$
\begin{equation}
  \epsilon (n) = 
  \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if } n = 1\\
    0 & \text{if } n > 1
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
One of the things I know for $g$, the Dirichlet inverse of $f$, is that the Dirichlet inverse of $f$ exists iff $f(1) \neq 0$. Assume $f(1) = 1$.
I used the same domain as the codomain for $g$ because the codomain of $f$ has to be the domain of $g$ and if $g$ is the Dirichlet inverse of $f$, then the domain is the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N} := \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,\cdots\}$.
For completely multiplicative functions $f$, the function $g = \mu \cdot f $ or equivalently, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $g(n) = \mu (n) f(n)$, where $\mu$ denotes the Mobius function. But if $g$ is bijective, then if
$$\omega (n) := \sum_{\substack{p|n \\ \text{primes } p}} 1$$
then $(f \circ g)(n) = f(g(n)) = f(\mu (n) f(n)) = n$, for all positive integers $n$. This means that $\omega (n)$ is even and $n$ is square-free. But for a such function $g$ it must work with ALL natural numbers $n$ and in general, $\omega (n)$ is not even. For example, for all positive primes $p$, $\omega (p) = 1$. This is a contradiction. Thus, $f$ is not completely multiplicative.
What other properties does $f$ and $g$ must satisfy? Is it possible to find such $f$ and $g$? If not, why?
Any hints are welcomed.

The requirement that $f, g$ both take values in $\mathbb{N}$ is already not consistent with the requirement that $f, g$ be Dirichlet inverses, even before you add on this other condition about $g$ also being the compositional inverse of $f$.
Namely, in order for $f$ and $g$ to be Dirichlet inverses we must have $\sum_{d \mid n} f(d) g \left( \frac{n}{d} \right) = 0$ for $n \ge 2$; this implies that if $f$ always takes positive values then $g$ must take some negative values, so it can't only take values in $\mathbb{N}$. Already taking $n = 2$ gives
$$f(1) g(2) + f(2) g(1) = 0$$
and $f(1) = 1$ implies $g(1) = 1$, so this gives $g(2) = - f(2)$. More generally taking $n = p$ to be prime gives $g(p) = - f(p)$ so if $f$ takes positive values then $g$ must take infinitely many negative values.

Ok. So, I think this means it is imposible, I guess. Right?

Yes, that's what I said.

Thank you! You helped a lot!
